# Inlining BibTeX bibliography in LaTeX file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am collaborating with another author using email to exchange latest version of the document. Is it possible to include the bibliography in the LaTeX file, so that we don't have to keep two files in synch? (however I would still like it to be in BibTeX format, I know you can have manual `\bibitems` in LaTeX files)

Comment: Since 2019, the `filecontents` package is not needed anymore. Here's how a bibliography could be included directly into the .tex file: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698139/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can include it using the `filecontents` environment:

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
% File contents here
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
...
```

This will extract the file *only* if it does not already exist locally. (You'll see this approach used a lot for examples on sites such as this one. It's handy for small snippets but is more awkward when things get very long.)

Comment: @Joseph: it makes more sense to load the package `filecontents` first and then writing the file. Then one can also edit the exported file and it will be updated, otherwise not.

Comment: @Herbert. I only ever use `filecontents` for a 'one-shot' unpack, so I will take your word for this.

Comment: @Joseph: and you never had typos in your "one shots" ;-) you are a lucky man

Comment: @Herbert. No, but I just delete the file (eventually, when I remember). I use `filecontents` for examples, so am usually attempting to keep additional packages down to a minimum.

Comment: @Joseph, is it possible to add this content at the end of the file (an not at the beginning)? That's where bibliography usually goes anyway...

Comment: BibTex doesn't seem to understand `filecontents`, it reports `I couldn't open database file ir.bib`

Answer (score 5):

You should use a revision control system for multiple author documents. There are a lot of programs like `subversion` or `git` or ... That makes the email exchange superflous and you get a backup system, too.

Comment: You are assuming that the co-authors are comfortable with this. That's fine if they are programmers, but if they are not then LaTeX alone may well be 'quite enough computer stuff'.

Comment: No, I didn't assume that. I said, that it is _really_ comfortable for multiple authors.

Comment: Again, I'll take your word for it: my co-authors get annoyed at me if I mention using anything other than Word (and I mean Word only: OpenOffice is already considered dangerous.)

Comment: Most VCSes have some GUIs nowadays (or so I'm told), so it really shouldn't be that difficult if they are already comfortable with handling TeX. Otherwise, on can always at least use [this technique](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-version-control-git-cvs-etc-in-latex-document/1124#1124) to keep files in sync at one side.

Comment: I was thinking about this (I am using mercurial just for myself), but it seems a bit too complicated to set up just to write 20 page long paper with this person. I agree its the best solution if we decide to work together on more projects.