# Using BibTex entries directly in .tex file

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Is there any way to use BibTex entries in thebibliography environment like following:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}

@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

\end{thebibliography}
```

For example consider that you want to quickly write a note that refers to three papers those their BibTex entries are available (perhaps via scholar.google.com ), it is easier that you directly insert them to your document instead of creating a .bib file or converting bibtex entries.

Comment: no that is not possible.

Comment: You can use `\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 ... \end{filecontents}` to create your bibliography on the fly, from one document. For extended filecontent environments, use the [filecontents package](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents).

Comment: You may want to look at the package `amsrefs`, where a syntax similar to that of `.bib` files is used.

Comment: @VafaKhalighi it means you only have to keep track of one file. I often don't want to share my entire bib file with collaborators.

Comment: @matth that seems like the start of an answer, but `filecontents` doesn't overwrite existing files so changes to the environment often don't get propagated.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub That seems to be one of the reasons why the filecontents package was developed. The normal filecontents environment does not overwrite files, but the filecontents environment provided by the filecontents packge does.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10201/inlining-bibtex-bibliography-in-latex-file

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Converting my comments into an answer: Maybe the [filecontents package](http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) can do what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum~\citep{goossens93}.
Dolor sit amet~\citet{greenwade93}.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname} 
\end{document}
```

In contrast to the filecontents environment provided by LaTeX2e, the filecontents environment provided by the filecontents packge does overwrite existing files.

Comment: remember that bibtex still has to be run separately.  no getting around that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: put `\immediate\write18{bibtex \jobname}` after the end of `filecontents` environment and run `pdflatex` with `shell-escape` option.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am not sure why but I had to remove the escape from the file name. Namely I had to change `\jobname` to `jobname`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, to a perhaps limited extent, with `amsrefs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsrefs}
\newenvironment{rezabib}
  {\bibdiv\biblist\setupbib}
  {\endbiblist\endbibdiv}

\def\setupbib{\catcode`@=\active}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`@
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1#{\gatherkey{#1}}
\def\gatherkey#1#2{\gatherkeyaux{#1}#2\gatherkeyaux}
\def\gatherkeyaux#1#2,#3\gatherkeyaux{\bib{#2}{#1}{#3}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\begin{rezabib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = {George D. Greenwade},
    title   = {The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})},
    year    = {1993},
    journal = {TUGBoat},
    volume  = {14},
    number  = {3},
    pages   = {342--351}
}

@book{goossens93,
    author    = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
    title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
    year      = {1993},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    address   = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}
\end{rezabib}

\end{document}
```

Note that you *must* use braces for delimiting fields. There should be no additional space in the starting lines for entries

```
@book{goossens93,
```

The limitation on spaces might be lifted, but *not* the one on delimiting braces. You can't use `@` in fields (also this may be lifted, if *really* needed).

Answer (score 0):

Since the update of the `filecontens` environment in 2019, the `filecontents` package is not needed anymore. Here's how a bibliography could be included directly into the .tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
    title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
    year      = {1993},
    publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
    address   = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{My article}
\author{John Doe}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}

Here's the reference: \cite{goossens93}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```