# biblatex: adding entries outside of main .bib file; possibly a 'multiple bibliographies' problem with filecontents package

Tags: biblatex

Is there a way to include additional entries outside of the `.bib` file in the a bibliography for `biblatex`? For instance, I have a few web references (http) which I don't want to add in my general `.bib` file, but only within a particular document (`.tex` file). Is this possible? I am imagining something which might use the filecontents package like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60649/using-bibtex-entries-directly-in-tex-file), but not sure how this can be done with `biblatex`.

Comment: Please consider reducing the length of the tile of your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply provide a second `.bib` file (this can be done with a `filecontents` environment specified in your `.tex` file) and use `\addbibresource` two times.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{general.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{specific.bib}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{general.bib}
\addbibresource{specific.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```