# How to use chapterbib package: syntax

Tags: bibliographies

I have read the documentation but I need a complete syntax for using chapterbib for global and chapterwise bibliography (not sectionwise) . It's very confusing at different posts and it does not work for me. It will be a great help if someone can tell me the complete steps to use it. Like `\usepackage {chapterbib}`.

Answer (score 7):

Chapterbib works on the `\include` commands. Here's a MWE:

Master file (e.g. `Master.tex`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

%% Hack to build a MWE
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Biblio.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
@book{goossens93,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
%% End of hack


\begin{document}
    \include{Chapter1}
    \include{Chapter2}
\end{document}
```

Content of `Chapter1.tex`:

```
One may cite \cite{greenwade93}.
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{Biblio}
```

Content of `Chapter2.tex`:

```
As detailed in~\cite{goossens93}...
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{Biblio}
```

**Compiling**

Since a bibliography is generated for each chapter, one may compile each one of them with `bibtex`. In our case:

```
pdflatex Master
bibtex Chapter1
bibtex Chapter2
pdflatex Master
pdflatex Master
```

**Overall bibliography**

If you want to sum up all entries used in the document, you need to add the following lines in your `Master` file:

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
```

and

```
\bibliography{Biblio}
```

Note that the first need to be called *before* any `\include` command. In addition, you need to compile the `Master` file with `bibtex` as well.

Note: the hack is taken from [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60675/61584).

Comment: Thanks Dorian. Its working now but is there any way that only those which are cited can be printed at the end of each chapter or for each chapter the bib file would be different, because I am getting all the references at the end of each chapter.

Comment: It strange, because this example is supposed to act as you want. Don't you use any `\nocite` command?

Comment: Dear Dorian, could you kindly elaborate on \nocite command. No I did not use it. How can it help?

Comment: Can anyone help with \nocite command usage for selective bibliography printing at the end of each chapter? I used \nocite{*} but its not working. even a link which explains the feature would help and I strongly suggest in this forum to keep biblatex and bibtex items separate. It has wasted much of my time. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok I tried it and instead of \citep I used \nocite and its working. I shall have to change all the citep to nocite now. but is it possible to change the heading "bibliography" to "references "?

Comment: `\include` can not be nested. but `chapterbib` needs `\include`, when every chapter is composed of several sections, what i should do?

Answer (score -2):

just to add in to the answer to Dorian and the example which is very helpful:
1. Use the example as given.
2. For selective references chapter wise make chapter wise .bib files and put them in the main folder ( not in the chapters folder where from you input or include)
3. Run pdfLatex + chapterwise (bibtex) + main (bibtex) + pdfLatex + PdfLatex.

To change the title of bibliography chapter wise or in main use \renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography} command or \renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}.
4. I dont think two styles one for chapter wise and one for global bibliography can be used so use one style for both because it might confuse the reader even if its possible to have two styles of citations.