# Commenting out large sections

Tags: comments

To "comment out" a line, I need to insert a `%` at the beginning of the line (so that the line will not be compiled).

Is there a way to comment out a large section without having to manually place `%` in front of each line?

Comment: Can you explain the sort of situations you want to do this in? If, for example, it's to reduce compile times when writing a long document then you may find it best to use something like the [subfiles](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfiles) package. This would mean you don't have to remove the commented out sections before compiling the whole document, but you could still compile individual parts of the document with the proper preamble, and without changing anything except for which file you pass to LaTeX.

Comment: Related: [Multi-line (block) comments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87303/multi-line-block-comments-in-latex)

Comment: I think the most comprehensive answer is still this one from the UK TeX FAQ:

http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=conditional

Comment: I don't use Context, but  I think scontents support Context. (however that's a relatively heavy comment, but at least it's built-in) Also iffalse should *still* work (because it's plain TeX?) ____________________________________________________________________________________________ See also: [Multi-line (block) comments in LaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87303/multi-line-block-comments-in-latex) and the [linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34482/contest-shoff-your-skillz-in-tex-friends-tex-sx-birthday/35017#35017) in its comment.

Answer (score 362, accepted):

You can use `\iffalse ... \fi` to make (La)TeX not compile everything between it. However, this might not work properly if you have unmatched `\ifxxx ... \fi` pairs inside them or do something else special with if-switches. It should be fine for normal user text.

There is also the `comment` package which gives you the `comment` environment which ignores everything in it verbatim. It allows you to define own environments and to switch them on and off. You would use it by placing `\usepackage{comment}` in the preamble. Below is an example:

```
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{document}
\section{Multi-line comments}}
\begin{comment}
This is a comment,
a multi-line comment,
indeed.
\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

Comment: make sure to `\usepackage{comment}` in the preamble

Comment: an example of the use of each of these would be good for this answer as it comes up in google

Comment: is there a way to fix \begin{comment} inside \begin \comment errors?

Comment: Here is [a link to an example](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comment/comment.pdf) usage of the `comment` package: Just use `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` to wrap the commented-out lines. (You must also include the package, of course - `\usepackage{comment}`.)

Comment: Can we see an example of, "[i]t allows you to define own environments and to switch them on and off?"

Answer (score 189):

You can use `\iffalse`:

```
\iffalse
One morning, as Gregor Samsa was waking up from anxious dreams, he discovered
that in his bed he had been changed into a monstrous verminous bug. He lay on
his armour-hard back and saw, as he lifted his head up a little, his brown,
arched abdomen divided up into rigid bow-like sections.
\fi
```

Of course, this has to align with other syntactical TeX structures in you document whereas you can use `%` much more freely. The good news is that you can introduce your own switch to make this optional:

```
\newif\ifdraft
\drafttrue % or \draftfalse

\ifdraft
<only shown in draft mode>
\else 
<only shown in non-draft mode>
\fi
```

The `\else` part is optional and you could use `\ifdraft ... \fi` if you don't need it.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but I saw a bug in your code! :)

Answer (score 113):

The `verbatim` package provides a `comment` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
    This text will be displayed
\begin{comment}
    This text will not be displayed.
\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

[The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) mentions this option on page 6 and remarks: "Note that this won’t work inside complex environments, like math for
example."

Answer (score 91):

Another option is the [`comment`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf) package, which, like `verbatim` provides a `comment` environment, but offers the option to define arbitrary "throw away" environments that can selectively be enabled or disabled:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

% uncomment to include stuff in standard comment-environment
%\includecomment{comment}

% define a mysection env which content is excluded
\excludecomment{mysection}

\begin{document}
    This text will be displayed
\begin{comment}
    This text will only be displayed, if \includecomment{comment} was given
\end{comment}
\begin{mysection}
    This text will only be displayed, if \includecomment{mysection} was given
\end{mysection}
\end{document}
```

Additionally, the package provides some simple hooks into the defined environments. Instead of `\includecomment{mysection}` one could also use `\specialcomment{mysection}{<before code>}{<after code>}` to enable a comment section:

```
% typeset stuff in mycomment with gray text
\specialcomment{mysection}{\begingroup\color{gray}}{\endgroup}
```

Answer (score 44):

There are other ways to solve this problem than via (La)TeX.

- You can use your editor's capabilities for commenting to comment out large sections. For instance, in Emacs <kbd>C-c ;</kbd> comments (or uncomments) the region (see e.g. http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Commenting.html#Commenting for details).
- You can use [version control](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1118/5701) so that you may delete large sections without being afraid to lose them.

Something that is good about either of these solutions is that they are independent of particular LaTeX packages and code.

Comment: I'd second this; Most text editors have this, and emacs is great for when I'm writing lots of math. For more text-based things, TeXStudio is also good, and has a similar feature.

Comment: Actually, <kbd>M-;</kbd> is even better (less keystrokes), and more intelligent (it does different things depending on e.g. whether region is active or not).

Comment: Worth noting, though, that my editor (Vim with LaTeX-Suite) is the reason I looked for this question *despite* already knowing how to line-comment en masse, because it screws up the folding. When I use the comment environment, I can fold up the whole commented-out part and only that part.

Comment: Also, uncommenting lines commented this way doesn't always work even in editors which support it in theory.  It is however pretty useful.

Comment: To supplement this answer: In TeXstudio it's Ctrl-T / Ctrl-U to comment and uncomment respectively.

Answer (score 27):

I often paste in plain text such as writing guidelines and comment them out. For me the simplest way is to define a command with an argument which produces no output.

```
\newcommand{\comm}[1]{}
```

And to comment out text:

```
\comm{
Text text text
}
```

Comment: I'm using same method. Just a detail, in the first code there's a missing backslash. It should be `\newcommand{\comm}[1]{}` (can't edit it, b/c of silly 6 characters rule).

Comment: There is a default function for this, which is `\typeout{}`.

Answer (score 15):

In vi or vim you could comment a section (say line 102-345) like this:

`[esc] [:]`

you are in command mode now! And type:

`102,345s/^/%/`

it means substitute the beginning of the line (^) with a % sign.

Comment: I find much more easy to use block-visual-mode insert: http://notfaq.wordpress.com/2006/07/28/vim-comment-blocks-of-code/

Comment: The second command inserts `%` in front of the lines 102 till 345... Note that this does not check if the line is already a comment.

Comment: Usually you DO NOT want to check if the line is already commented, because you can later do `102,345s/^%//` and leave any previously commented line commented.

Answer (score 13):

*This answer obviously depents of the frontend one is using, but in the case of using Kile:*

---

#### Commenting multiple lines with Kile

1) Select the lines you wish to comment out

2) `Ctrl - D`

---

#### Uncommenting multiple lines with Kile

1) Select the lines you wish uncomment

2) `Ctrl - Shift - D`

---

These shortcuts can be changed from `Settings -> Configure Shortcuts...`

Comment: `cntrl+/` also works

Answer (score 12):

Anything written after `\end{document}`  will be ignored by the compiler. I often use this to cut a document short when troubleshooting, by inserting a second `\end{document}` at the appropriate place.

Comment: +1: Of course this only works if the section to comment out is from some line _x_ to the end of the document. But if that is the case,  this is easy and effective! I frequently use the area after `\end{document}` to keep larger chunks of "material I do not want to delete, yet"

Answer (score 11):

For the sake of completeness, I will include the shortcuts for the few editors that I know (with the links to their corresponding original answers).

- **[Texmaker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91434/32209)**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to comment

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment

You can customize them

- **[WinEdt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262080/32209)**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to comment

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> to uncomment

Yes, that's four keys (!). However, you can install [ToggleComment](http://www.winedt.org/macros/text/ToggleComment.html) (a macro) to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to toggle between comment and uncomment a block of text.

Answer (score 3):

If using TeXNicCenter, you can highlight the text and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to comment the text out

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to uncomment it

Answer (score 1):

> Is there way to comment out a large section without having to manually putting a % in front of each line?

Not probably what you are looking for, but another approach to easily hide sections is work with  child files. It is a rather simple process. Assuming commons usual shortcuts of commons editors (i.e, excluding vim/emacs) will be some like that:

1. Select the section to comment
2. <kbd>Crtl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> (cut)
3. Write `%\input{filename}`
4. <kbd>Crtl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> (new document)
5. <kbd>Crtl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> (paste)
6. <kbd>Crtl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> `filename.tex` (save the new document).

   *Et voilá*. Hereafter restore or comment the section again is as simple as remove/add ***one*** `%` before `\input`. Bonus points: (a)The commented part barely can  bothers you while working in the main document and (b) prevent you of accidental deletions on the commented parts (that obviously cannot be detected in the pdf).