# Skip compilation of parts of a document

Tags: comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commenting out large sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/commenting-out-large-sections)

I have a long document where sometimes I need to omit some parts for the compilation, and sometimes other parts. I do it by just commenting with `%` the necessary lines, but sometimes it gets tedious. I wonder if there are some commands which, put at the start and end of the part I want to avoid, would skip the compilation of that part.

Comment: Flow: May I ask what editor are you using for your LaTeX writing? And I may have a solution for you. The reason being is that I don't know if this method works across all editors which I would think it doesn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another option is to restructure your document so that you have

- one main file
- many chapter/section files

You can then use `\include` or `\input` to link the chapter/section files to the main file.

**mainfile.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}

\end{document}
```

**chaper1.tex**

```
This is in chapter 1
```

**chapter2.tex**

```
This is in chapter 2
```

See [When should I use \input vs. \include?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) to compare `\include` to `\input`

There are many advantages to this approach- not least, that you can comment out the relevant `\include` line which will stop you from compiling that chapter.

Answer (score 16):

You should look at the [`comment` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment). It is specifically meant for this purpose. It provides a `comment` environment (or a `\comment...\endcomment` command pair) that you need to encompass your don't-want-to-compile stuff with. It also allows a form of version control, `versionA` (say), which can be turned on/off using `\includecommand{versionA}`/`\excludecomment{versionA}`. Such version-specific comments have their own environment: `\begin{versionA}...\end{versionA}` or the `\versionA...\endversionA` command pair.

Here's a minimal working example (the second paragraph `\lipsum[2]`, prefixed with `2.`, is not typeset):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}% http://ctan.org/pkg/comment
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
1.\ \lipsum[1]
\begin{comment}
  2.\ \lipsum[2]
\end{comment}
3.\ \lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: Commented paragraph using comment package]

Answer (score 11):

You might be interested by the [tagging](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tagging) package (born on TeX.SX not long ago) which allows to set tags for the document and conditionally adapt the document depending on the set tags.

Combine it with `\include` statements like cmhughes recommended.