# Hide a paragraph

Tags: sectioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commenting out large sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/commenting-out-large-sections)

I have in my document a paragraph that I want to keep in my tex source. But when generating the PDF, I don't want it to appear.

How can I hide a paragraph or a whole section ?

Comment: Perhaps have a look at some packages like `verbatim` (`comment` environment).

Comment: You can sandwich the paragraph or section with a conditional construct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put a `%` at the beginning of every line, or if there are no fancy if-constructs already in the code it is sometimes simpler to put

```
\iffalse
```

before the section and

```
 \fi
```

after the section.

Or there are comment and other packages which give you `comment` environments if you would rather use an environment form.