# Hiding and revealing interlaced paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Commenting out large sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/commenting-out-large-sections)

I am writing a document and I want to prepare two versions.

Version 1 will contain the 'text'. 
Version 2 will contain the 'text' as well paragraphs of 'commentary'. The layout will interlace the two types of text e.g:

text paragraph

commentary paragraph

text paragraph

commentary paragraph 
and so on.

Ideally, I would be able to produce the two versions from one source file by simply altering a parameter in the preamble. I imagine that I might be able to create an environment called commentary (or similar) such that all instances on the commentary environment can be hidden by altering a statement in the preamble.

I hope this makes sense I am relatively new to latex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I suggest you to look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62096/4427

Comment: I believe that does exactly what I want! thanks kindly egreg!

Comment: Also, I imagine that using some trickery with redefining `\par` you probably might be able to obtain what you want (i.e., hiding *every other paragraph*) automatically.  This, however, might not work when using anything else than text (from figures to enumerations).

Comment: There is also an `extract` package, which might be even better for you; it allows e.g. to generate a *second* LaTeX file, with only specified environments.

Comment: @KindergartenCop I suggest to close this question as duplicate, then, with a link to the other question and answer.

Comment: is that something I should do, or is that something an admin would have to do? In any case I agree. Despite my efforts to find the answer by search it is very similar to the other question

Comment: @KindergartenCop You don't have to do anything. We're waiting for other contributions from you to the site.