# Multi-line (block) comments in LaTeX

Tags: comments

In LaTeX, `%` can be used for single-line comments. For multi-line comments, the following command is available in the `verbatim` package.

```
\begin{comment}
Commented code
\end{comment}
```

But is there a simple command like `/* code */` in C?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Commenting out large sections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17816)

Comment: Also see: [Block comments in TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35017/323)

Comment: Your question was pretty enough for me.

Comment: `\usepackage{verbatim}`

Comment: if you are using overleaf, you could try the hotkey `Ctrl + /` (`command + /` on a Mac) to toggle commenting for selected lines. (Comment/ uncomment selected text).

Comment: The comment environment in the verbatim package is more of a by-product. The 'comment' package I find more robust.

Answer (score 284):

Following the C code paradigm, where one can use the preprocessor directives

```c
#if 0
junk code
#endif
```

something similar can be done in `TeX` (and descendants):

```
\iffalse
I don't want this to happen
\fi
```

The commented parts can be easily activated by replacing `\iffalse` with `\iftrue`.

Comment: @Aditya What would you say is a good and stable way to comment things out? Say, stable in so far as I am not doing anything fancy ---- just commenting out a chunk of code in its plain version. I have also got trouble with block-comment using the  `\begin{comment}` environment, either from the `verbatim` package or `comments` package.

Comment: The of @Aditya is dead. Here is the new link: https://texfaq.org/FAQ-conditional and an archive version: https://web.archive.org/web/20210813002049/https://texfaq.org/FAQ-conditional

Answer (score 103):

A simple solution I use is

```
\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{}
```

Which just defines a command that does nothing with the input (effectively commenting it out!)

Sample use:

```
\mycomment{
This line of text won't show

This one won't either
}
```

*Edit: Replaced `comment` with `mycomment` since the former conflicts with the semi-popular `comment` package. This way, if you reuse commented blocks in a project that uses the `comment` package, nothing will break.*

Comment: If I just want to disable `section*{}` (and not displaying it, why woudn't `\renewcommand{\section}[1]{}` work ? Is there a work around? Thanks.

Comment: Long story short, starred commands are parsed differently from the normal version. See https://texfaq.org/FAQ-cmdstar. If you wanted to hide `section*` blocks, you can do (on separate lines): `\usepackage{suffix}`, `\WithSuffix\newcommand\section*[1]{}`

Comment: I prefer this solution, as it seems much more readable/verbose to me then the `\iffalse ... \fi` suggestion.

Comment: This is very easy to use. Thanks

Answer (score 60):

No, but you can define something close:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\long\def\/*#1*/{}

AAA

\/* This is a test
    and this is another
*/

BBB
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make ``\* multiline comments *\`` ?

Comment: @GarbageCollector You can but then it means changing the catcode of the backtick to make it active and would cause a lot of grief in other areas. Ah! did not see your edit ... changing catcode of slash will give you same headaches.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: Of course, this definition cannot be nested. With LuaTeX it is possible to have multiline comments without any catcode jugglery. See [Block comments in TeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35017/323) for an example.

Comment: It redefines `\*` and requires a space after the closing delimiter but, `\def\*#1*\ {}` works I think.

Comment: Just a heads-up, this broke `\url{}` in BibTex for me. (Sadly)

Comment: @domenukk Can you please post a question with a MWE? There might be a solution.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a poor man's version of the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35017/14100) linked by Aditya above.  It doesn't require ConTeXt but it does need to be compiled with LuaTeX.  With it you can use C style comments: `/*comment*/`.  A potential downside is that it "works" even in a `verbatim` environment.  It works in all situations I can think of.

This input:

[image]

Gives this output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}

commenting = false
local gsub = string.gsub

local opencomm = "%/%*(.*)"
local closecomm = "(.-)%*%/"

function comment(s)
    if not commenting then
        s = gsub(s,opencomm,
                function(s1)
                commenting = true
                s1 =  gsub(s1,closecomm,function(s2) commenting = false return "" end,1)
                  if commenting then return "" else
                      return comment(s1)
                  end
              end
            )
    else
        s = gsub(s,"(.+)",
                function(s3)
                s3 =  gsub(s,closecomm,function(s4) commenting = false return "" end,1)
                    if commenting then return "%" else
                        return comment(s3)
                    end
                end
                )
    end
    return s
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer', comment, 'comment')
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

1 /*HIDDEN*/ 2

1 /*HIDDEN
HIDDEN*/ 2

1/*HIDDEN
HIDDEN
HIDDEN*/2

1 /*HIDDEN 
HIDDEN*/ 2 /*HIDDEN*/ 3

1 /*HIDDEN*/ 2 /*HIDDEN
HIDDEN*/ 3

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

I think the most straightforward way to do this is to use a TeX editor. TeXnicCenter for instance offers to comment and uncomment marked blocks by ctrl+q and ctrl+w. This simply adds a '%' at the respective lines. This further grays out commented section, which is not the case with scripted solutions.

Comment: you can't have inline comments as such for example 
`2 /* HIDDEN HIDDEN HIDDEN */ 3`

Comment: This is true of course. A scripted version also lets hide/show comments by a simple compile flag, which can be great in drafting or reviewing work.

Answer (score 4):

Short: put `\directlua{--` before the block and a single `}` after the block when compiling with Lua(La)TeX.

Long: this is a "bug" of LuaTeX turned into a feature, or what make programmers happy. Putting a double hyphen in front of a text in Lua means a single-line comment; however, since TeX strips newlines from Lua code, this appears as a single-line chunk to Lua and so all the chunk gets commented.

**Not tested**, but I think you could alias that as

```
\newcommand{\multlinecomment}[1]{\directlua{-- #1}}
```

and then enclose your comment as in

```
\multlinecomment{
  My multiline
  comment
  with Lorem ipsum.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me and I think it is very simple and good enough. Highlight the text that you want to comment using your mouse or keyboard. Once highlighted use `Ctrl+t` This will comment the selection. You can uncomment the selection by using same steps on commented text.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Am I missing something, or your answer only works for a specific text editor?

Comment: In my experience this works TeXstudio and Texmaker. In Overleaf you can use `Ctrl+/` as mentioned in one of the questions comments.

Comment: Can I do this easily in vim?