# LuaLaTeX -- Attempt to index global 'luatexbase'

Tags: luatex, luacode

I'm working on a LuaLaTeX-Document project using my laptop and a desktop PC.
The document contains a LuaLaTeX script to enable C-Style comments ([link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87922)).
However, while compilation works fine on my laptop, on the desktop PC the error

```
! LuaTeX error ./cStyleComments.lua:30: attempt to index global 'luatexbase' (a 
nil value)
stack traceback:
    ./cStyleComments.lua:30: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
l.24 \directlua{require("cStyleComments.lua")}
```

occurs.

`cStyleComments.lua` contains the definition of `comments` method and line 30, which reads:

```
luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer', comment, 'comment')
```

LuaLaTeX version on laptop: beta-0.80.0
LuaLaTeX version on PC: beta-0.79.1  (I have no sudo, so I cannot upgrade).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to use the `luatexbase` package:

```
\usepackage{luatexbase}
```

However I don't know why it works without on the laptop system.

Comment: I may be wrong, but perhaps this is caused by one of your systems not to have the latest packages versions?

Comment: the code from luatexbase has been added to the kernel in a newer latex.