# LuaLaTeX and mylatexformat precompiling not working

Tags: compiling, preamble, mylatexformat

I am trying to use `mylatexformat` to precompile my lengthy preamble, which is basically all in my custom `.cls`, with the remaining bit of non-static preamble at the top of my `main.tex`, before which I put `\csname endofdump\endcsname` (I have also tried just `\endofdump`). I use VSCode (LaTeX Workshop) and my distribution is MiKTeX. I have successfully generated the `main.fmt` file by using the command `lualatex -ini -jobname="main" --shell-escape "&lualatex" mylatexformat.ltx "main.tex"`. Once I have the `.fmt`, I put `%&main` on the very first line of my `main.tex` and run the command `lualatex --shell-escape "&main" main.tex`, however, I keep on getting this error:

```
    (./main.tex[\directlua]:1: attempt to index a nil value (global 'shellesc')
    stack traceback:
            [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
    \write ->\directlua {shellesc.write_or_execute()}
```

I thought this might be due to me not having the `shellesc.sty` tool in MiKTeX, but I do, and `--shell-escape` is working and produces `minted` output, when I'm not using `mylatexformat` ofcourse. A very similar error shows up [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364034/lualatex-attempt-to-index-global-luatexbase), but their issue was fixed by just installing a missing package it seems.

[Here is my `main.log`](https://pastebin.com/rT4vk3vc) directly after generating the `.fmt`, and [here](https://pastebin.com/1mPNFMkt) is a log file after issuing the second command.

I can't think of any other details to include to help the debug process, but can definitely add more if needed. Although I am running it using lualatex, I ultimately want to be able to use `latexmk -lualatex ...` for automation, but I don't know if that's possible with mylatexformat...

Comment: you can not save Lua state or Opentype fonts in the format so precompiling the format with lualatex is tricky.

Comment: luatex does not have the same `\write18` mechanism to access the shell so minted (via shellesc package) uses Lua to access the shell if used by luatex, but if you load shellesc.sty into the format the tex interface is saved but all the underlying Lua definitions are dropped so, as you show you get undefiend names in Lua

Comment: Might be a stupid question... but... what if I precompiled my `.cls` (excluding the lualatex dependent fonts, etc.) in pdflatex for example, and then added the font in the dynamic part of the preamble and compiled with lualatex?

Comment: no the format is engine specific , tex isn't a compiler there isn't really any compiled form of a class or package file, the fmt is just  a dump of the state of the engine at that time (it used to be literally a core dump of the machine memory not so in recent decades but still engine specific). Just don't load packages using lua in your preloaded preamble, and load them in the document using the format.

Comment: Just curious, are you using `mylatexformat` to speed up compiling or to just reduced pre-amble? For the latter, you can just make a standalone file for your pre-amble as a .sty and use `RequirePackage`. I used `mylatexformat` a fair bit in the past, but didn't really notice compile speed improvement. Not that important to me anyways.

Comment: @likethevegetable, I already have most of my `\RequirePackage`s and settings in my custom `labreport.cls` class file. Is this different from using a `.sty`?

Comment: For most intents, they're the same. Have you seen noticeable speed gains with mylatexformat?

Comment: I only got mylatexformat to work once with pdflatex, not at all with lualatex, and by moving a good few of my packages to the dynamic section of the preamble, but then, yes I did see a big improvement. During a regular compile, VSCode tells me that about 40 seconds is being spent doing the preamble, of 52 seconds total in a 4-run latexmk compile, but with mylatexformat it was about 14 seconds total.