# Choose what to compile without uncomment long texts

Tags: xetex, latex3

How can I select which section I want to compile and which section I do not want to compile? I am using XeLatex to compile the document. Sometimes the text in each section is long and I don't want to comment and uncomment all of the text inside the section every time I run the script. Every time I am running, need to compile different set of sections. It would be easier to have an easy way to do it. Or just comment/uncomment a particular section line instead of comment/uncommenting the whole text inside.

The question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142417/what-are-your-best-practices-to-compile-only-a-part-of-the-document-or-presentat), suggests to break the file in to multiple files and then run the main script (within the main script one can choose the desirable file(s) to compile). However, I am interested to know is it possible to do it within a single file?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 
\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[big]{layaureo}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt} 

\usepackage{tabularx}           

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\section{Personal Data}

some text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text here


\section{Education}
some text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text here

\section{Work Experience}

some text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text here


\section{Hobbies}
some text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text here

\section{Interests}
some text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text here

\section{Skills}
some text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text here

\section{MISC}
some text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text heresome text here

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about the possibilities mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/commenting-out-large-sections) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87303/multi-line-block-comments-in-latex)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the cleanest way to do this is separate your long sections into individual files. You would have a `.tex` file for each section you wish to compile separately. For your example, you'd have some directory that would look like this:

```
./
../
main.tex
personal_data.tex
education.tex
...
...
misc.tex
```

Then in your `main.tex` file you'd have:

```
% preamble and document definition
\input{personal_data.tex}
\input{education.tex}
...
...
\input{misc.tex}
```

To exclude some sections from the compilation, you then only need to comment out the single line containing the `\input{}` command for that file.

If you absolutely hate the idea of having multiple files for one output document, you can use the [`comment`](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment?lang=en) package. It allows you to selectively exclude portions of the text you've wrapped in its environment. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

% Comment environment definitions
\includecomment{PersonalData}
\excludecomment{Education}

\begin{document}
    This text will be displayed

\begin{PersonalData}
    This text will NOT be displayed.
\end{PersonalData}

\begin{Education}
    This text will be displayed.
\end{Education}

\end{document}
```

NOTE: From the [package documentation](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf):

> The opening and closing commands should appear on a line of their own. No starting spaces, nothing after it. This environment should work with arbitrary amounts of comment, and the comment can be arbitrary text.

Comment: is it possible to do it without breaking into multiple files?

Comment: @Jack updated answer

Comment: @Teepeemm You are absolutely right about the `\excludecomment{}`, and I fixed it in my example code. I don't believe a `\verb` is needed, however; the [package documentation](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf) does not specify anything like that for its usage.