# Is it compatible to define comment-like latex newcommands for jinja delimiters?

Tags: macros, jinja-template

I am starting to use [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/) for creating templates in latex. From what I saw, it is necessary to change the default jinja delimiters (`{%` and `%}`, for example) to avoid conflicts with delimiters used by latex. I have been given the following setup to use as starting point:

```
env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader(pages_module, 'templates'),
    autoescape=False, 
    block_start_string='<#',
    block_end_string='#>',
    variable_start_string='<<',
    variable_end_string='>>',
    comment_start_string='<%',
    comment_end_string='%>',
)
```

The problem is that now my IDE complains that I can't "use macro parameter character # in horizontal mode" in the latex template files. Maybe it is a bit of a silly request, but I would like to get rid of these false errors that may obfuscate other problems my IDE could detect on the file. Looking at this [alternative](http://eosrei.net/articles/2015/11/latex-templates-python-and-jinja2-generate-pdfs) set of delimiters and considering the possibility to define new commands with comment-like behavior such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/484219), would there be any problems with defining the following environment for Jinja:

```
env = Environment(
    loader=PackageLoader(pages_module, 'templates'),
    autoescape=False, 
    block_start_string='\JBLOCK{',
    block_end_string='}',
    variable_start_string='\JVAR{',
    variable_end_string='}',
    comment_start_string='<%', # or whatever, I don't plan to use jinja comments
    comment_end_string='%>',
)
```

And then using this in the latex template:

```
\newcommand{\JBLOCK}[1]{}
\newcommand{\JVAR}[1]{}
(...)
\JBLOCK{ block body }
\JBLOCK{ endblock body }
(...)
```

Do I risk getting some unexpected behavior or hard to pinpoint conflicts down the line by using something like that?

Comment: If Jinja does its job of replacing the blocks by the actual code then it should be fine. However, using `}` as block closing character seems tricky because you also might need to use that character inside of the blocks (because it is a very common character in LaTeX) which would require some kind of escaping. Maybe using `#>` and trying to get your editor to stop producing that specific warning would be easier.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Marijn. What do you mean inside the block? You mean inside of the `\JBLOCK{ <here> }`? Or between `\JBLOCK{block body}` and `\JBLOCK{endblock body}`? Because in the second case it should be allright, no? Jinja is not going to try "close" a block indication that is not open (afaiu `}` does not signal the end of the block, but the end of a block marker). And I can't now imagine a case in which I would need to use a `}` inside of the block marker. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: you are right, I misinterpreted your syntax slightly - if the blocks indeed consist of `for element in data` type of statements (which presumably is the case, also with `if` etc) then there should be no problem.