# How can I comment out a block of text in texmaker?

Tags: texmaker, comments

I use texmaker and some time ago I found, by chance, a way to comment many lines at once, but I can't remember it now.
Can somebody remind me of that?

Comment: It surely depends on the editor you are using...

Comment: Are you maybe thinking of the `comment` package and its `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` instructions?

Comment: @DiegoSilvera If you want to comment out large blocks in your LaTeX code you might look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/commenting-out-large-sections. On the other hand, if you really want to comment out using `%` for many lines this would be editor-dependent.

Comment: An addition to the answer by hpesoj626: If you look through the menus in Texmaker (File, Edit, Tools etc.) you will find that, as in many other programs, keyboard shortcuts are listed next to menu entries. For example, if you look under the Edit menu, you will find *Comment*, and next to that the keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + T).

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To comment several lines at once in TeXMaker, select the lines and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. To uncomment, click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

### Edit

To follow up on  Torbjørn's comment, you can see the mostly used keyboard shortcuts under menu

> Edit > Comment

You will see all of the default keyboard shortcuts and customize your keyboard shortcuts under menu

> Options > Configure Texmaker > Shortcuts

One of the shortcuts I find helpful is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> which toggles between pdf viewer and editor, especially when I use a lot of applications and workspaces at once.

Answer (score 4):

In LaTex or PC Tex: Select the text you want to block or turn into a comment and use  Ctrl Shift % Hold all three keys at once.

Comment: I understand that PCTeX has an integrated editor; but this doesn't work in "LaTeX" generically, does it?