# is there a way of putting % in front of a whole chunk of text?

Tags: texmaker, comments

`%` starts an end-of-line comment in LaTeX. Is there any way I comment an entire paragraph without putting a `%` in front of each individual line?

Note: I write my LaTeX code in `texmaker`.

Comment: Hi! This quite depends on your text editor. For instance in TeXworks, this is done by selecting the lines and pressing `Ctrl+{` (= `Ctrl+Shift+[` on English keyboard).

Comment: Most LaTeX friendly editors have this feature, often called `Outcomment` or `Comment out`

Comment: take a look at [How to write hidden notes in a LaTeX file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11177/579)

Comment: In `texmaker` the comment and uncomment are in the `Edit` menu. Comment out is `Ctrl-t` and uncomment is `Ctrl-u`, just highlight the reqion to be commented and hit `Ctrl-t`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `verbatim` package provides a `comment` environment for dealing with chunks of the input:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

Normal text that will be printed.

\begin{comment}
  Text and other input \( x^2 \) that will be ignored.

\section{Heading}
\label{sec:heading}

Even this heading.
\end{comment}

Further material that will be printed.

\end{document}
```

Comment: didn't work after doing this, does it mean i don't have the package? would there be a compiling error if if i write \usepackage{verbatim}, but I don't actually have it?

Comment: @Lost1 `verbatim` is part the standard distributions.  What error do you get?

Comment: I would not recommend using `comment` as it is really easy to miss that this is commented out (unless your editor is good a coloring the contents of the `comment` env). Most LaTeX friendly editors mark outcommented lines very visually and is thus prefered

Comment: texmaker highlights something in orange when it is a comment it does not recognise - this is exactly what happened. If i just add the package into the file, there is no error in compiling but it does not recognise the \begin{comment} command

Comment: Then please provide more information about your document, ie post a MWE

Answer (score 6):

If the question is how to comment a block of text without *manually* adding a `%` at the beginning of each line, you can do the following in texmaker.

### Mac OS

Select the block of text you want to comment and hit

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to comment, and

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment.

### Windows/Linux (I think...)

Select the block of text you want to comment and hit

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to comment, and

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment.

Comment: i tried ctrl+T for windows, didn't work, sorry. :(

Comment: @Lost1, you can see the actual shortcut in the `Edit` menu.

Comment: @Lost1 See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91432/comment-many-lines

Comment: Just tested latest TM on windows, I cannot get `Ctrl-t` to react in my virtual Win7 either. You will have to choose *comment* from the `Edit` menu using the mouse. Might also be an idea to report this to the developers. (Though this may be an effect of the virtualizaition software I use)

Comment: @daleif I don't have a Windows machine. Perhaps you should [report it](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) to them (him, really).

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`comment` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) for this exact functionality [and more](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/comment/comment.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}

A

\begin{comment}

XYZ

\end{comment}

\end{document}
```