# Dynamically set if environment should be printed

Tags: pdf, environments, conditionals, printing

Is it possible to tell LaTeX whether or not some environments should be printed in the output PDF file?

I want to create one version of my document with "extended" examples and another with fewer examples. I tried to use the `ifthen` package, but I didn't get anywhere...

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62096/2417) help?

Comment: look at for example the comment package that allows you to declare an environment to be effectively a comment.