# Commenting out large blocks in the preamble when in draft mode

Tags: conditionals, comments, preamble

I would like something to enable me to comment out large blocks of my preamble when I've specified that my document is a draft.

The `comment` environment provided by the `verbatim` package works well for commenting out a large block of my preamble. The problem I am having is that I'm not sure how to make the `comment` enviroment active only when the draft option is specified in `\documentclass[draft]{article}`.

How do I make the inclusion/activation of this `comment` environment conditional upon the specification of the `draft` option? If that is not possible, is there some work around, perhaps through the creation of new booleans and something like `\ifbool`?

Comment: This is covered in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17816/15925

Comment: @AndrewSwann Indeed it is. For some reason I thought that it would only work in the body of the document and not in the preamble. But, actually paying attention to the log, it became clear that I just made a silly typo that caused an error when defining the conditional. I also had a bit of redundancy since with the conditional solution you don't even need the `comment` enviroment. Over-complicating things for myself. Issuing a vote to close as duplicate.