# Remove frame from presentation

Tags: beamer

Question: how do I remove a frame from my presentation?

I am using the beamer package and I just want to remove 1 frame quickly from my presentation because it is not relevant. Is there a quick way to do this? Like

```
\begin{frame}[exclude]
\end{frame}
```

Comment: The answer of @dcmst is correct. After my post I also came across this topic, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/commenting-out-large-sections. In my case it was also sufficient to use the `\iffalse ... \fi` statements

Comment: I think in the specific case of a `beamer` presentation the answer here is probably preferable to the general 'commenting out' one. Also, the question is distinct: nice one!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

use `<presentation:0>`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<presentation:0>
1
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
3
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
4
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
5
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Obligatory gif:
[image]

The slide number is still incremented by slides hidden in this way. If you don't wish to number hidden slides, add the argument

```
\begin{frame}<presentation:0>[noframenumbering]
```

Comment: You can omit the `presentation:` if you want to just hide the slide from any kind of mode (e.g. handout), like `\begin{frame}<0>[noframenumbering]`

Comment: Any idea how to get `noframenumbering` to work with `fragile`?

Comment: @JoMo, that sounds like a question that needs its own SO post.

Comment: First comment, from @Mitja, indicates that just putting `<0>` will work. Right now, it does not in my Latex installation. But the code `<presentation:0>` works as indicated.

Comment: The [Beamer User Guide](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) suggests in 8.4 that `<0>` works and also that they automatically get the `[noframenumbering]` today. You could try `<all:0>` and see if that does something and maybe look into if the `beamer` package you have installed is up to date.

Comment: "Frames which are hidden with `<0>` behave like the `noframenumbering` option and will not be counted for the number of frames (this only applies if no mode is specified, e.g. not for `<all:0>`)", Beamer User Guide , v3.70, p. 77.