# How do I skip slides in Beamer?

Tags: beamer

I have a beamer presentation for a long presentation, but I'd like to make a smaller presentation which skips some of the slides. Does beamer have a way to do that, or should I just comment out the source code for the slides I want to skip?

Comment: If you cut the code and paste in new files, you can use `\include{}` to compile only what you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define your own if condition and just wrap every additional slide inside of `\ifadditional` ... `\fi`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newif\ifadditional
\additionaltrue
%\additionalfalse % UNCOMMENT TO CREATE SMALLER VERSION

\begin{document}

\frame{Frame 1}

\ifadditional
\frame{Frame 2 -- Additional Slide}
\fi

\frame{Frame 3}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Found an alternative solution at: [Remove frame from presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200151/remove-frame-from-presentation)

It does not require to add new definitions, but you can't encapsulate many frames at once.

It simply consists on adding `<0>` after `\begin{frame}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<0>
1
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}<0>[noframenumbering]
skipping frame numbering
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
3
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
4
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does this work?

Answer (score 6):

With the `beameraudience` package you can create different versions of the presentation based on keywords of your choice:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[
    audience=long
    ]{beameraudience}

\begin{document}

\frame{Frame 1}

\justfor{long}{%
    \frame{Frame 2 -- Additional Slide} 
}


\frame{Frame 3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any convenient way to run latex with a parameter, or is the recommended way to change the header, compile, rename/save pdf, and change header again?

Comment: @FooBar You can use constructs like `\def\foo{bar}\input{documentname}` and then pass `\foo` as package option. Or use different jobnames, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327352/36296 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document

Comment: Can I call the value of the `audience` variable in a slide, so that the slide can have some sort of statement about it being a specific variant (and where the name of the variant is auto-populated)?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Is there a way to have \justfor evaluate to True if it matches any one of a list of possible audiences?

Answer (score 2):

The beamer package offers a 'handout' mode. You can mark frames to be only printed in the 'beamer' (projector) version, to be only printed in the handout version or in both. The beameruserguide explains how to do this.