# cite an author without generating the bibliography at the end of the document

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I would like to ask about the inverse of this [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17128/using-bibtex-to-make-a-list-of-references-without-having-citations-in-the-body-o) if you please.

In other words: Using BibTeX, how to cite references in the context (showing author's name) without having the bibliography at the end the document?

For example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
text ..........

text...... \cite{patygore}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method described in [Remove frame from presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200151/remove-frame-from-presentation). The following code generates a single frame that looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\cite{article-full}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<presentation:0>
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Other alternative

If switching to `biblatex` ([What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)) is an option this is certainly easy, just leave out the `\printbibliography` statement.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\textcite{aksin} \parencite{angenendt}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry when I use \usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex} the beamer is explosed with errors

Comment: Dont forget please the document class is a beamer not an articl

Comment: @AH That doesn't matter, `biblatex` works just fine with `beamer` as well. Try deleting all the auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`) and recompile. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex.

Comment: @AH See updated answer.