# Is it possible to hide a section or comment out a whole section?

Tags: comments

I want to comment out a whole section in order to save the text but not render it in the PDF. Is this possible?

Comment: Put a comment sign `%` at the beginning of every line of the section, use package `comment` or use a conditional test i wont show you, because it is bad.

Comment: Yes the verbatim package solves this problem to a very good degree.

Comment: Hm, the conditional i wouldn't show has the highest vote count.

Comment: What do you mean @Johannes_B? I like the verbatim solution, how about you?

Comment: @LoveLearning I like it too, but the other question has higher voted answers. Those work perfectly fine and i use the `\iffalse` trick myself everyday. But it isn't the cleanest of solutions.

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out in the comments, there is a solution to this problem. For me, the `verbatim` package worked out the easiest. [As given here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17822/39323)

The solution is simply

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
    This text will be displayed
\begin{comment}
    This text will not be displayed.
\end{comment}
\end{document}
```