# Which Windows editors have comment/ uncomment keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: windows, editors, texniccenter

I'm a longtime user of TeXnicCenter.  I like the fact that there's a keyboard shortcut I can use to comment or uncomment large blocks of text (Ctrl-Q and Ctrl-W, respectively).  Are there other LaTeX editors for Windows 7 that also have this feature?

Comment: emacs, of course!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Quick, answer, before the vim - mafia comes in ;-)

Comment: WinEdt has that feature.

Comment: As already noted, several editors have this ability. Beyond that, what are you after as an answer here? We could logically have one per editor, which seems rather 'weak', or one (CW?) answer, or ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might want to take a look at [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/32888).

Comment: I want a list which I can cross-reference with the Wikipedia chart of LaTeX editors.  It would be nice to know whether a particular editor is recommended aside from its shortcuts, too (but I'm afraid I already joined the vim mafia).

Comment: Texmaker -- highlight the appropriate lines.  cntl-T to comment  out and cntl-W to uncomment highlighted lines.  Caution: this action prepends % or trims them one at a time, so be careful with already commented code.

Comment: Emacs uses the same shortcut to comment and uncomment, so you don't even need to remember two of them.

Comment: Notepad++ has `Ctrl+k` for commenting and `Shift+Ctrl+k` to uncomment.

Comment: vim together with https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary

Comment: My concern here is that one could ask similar open-ended questions about almost any feature of any editor, with the result that the nature of a good answer is very hard to determine. Could you perhaps details what it is that motivates the question: as you seem to be happy with TeXnicCenter I'm not seeing it!

Comment: I would mark @R.Schumacher's comment as "best answer" if it were an answer: it told me that TeXMaker handles comments in the way I'm used to, and led me to download TeXMaker and try it out.

Answer (score 4):

In Winedt use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to comment a line and to uncomment a line use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

Comment: Four-key shortcuts?!? Does anyone else find that excessive? I block comment/ uncomment code hundreds of times a day when writing code. Is that really unusual behaviour? A four-key "shortcut" suggests it's not expected to be used very often.

Comment: [ToggleComment](http://www.winedt.org/macros/text/ToggleComment.html), a WinEdt macro, allows you to (un)comment blocks using  Ctrl + Q

Answer (score 1):

All of them.  Unless you count Notepad.  Seriously, I dare you to find a single LaTeX editor that does not.  I use TexWorks.  The shortcut there is a bit annoying since it requires 3 fingers: ctrl+shift+] and ctrl+shift+[

Comment: In WinEdt it requires *four* fingers... Shift+Ctrl+Alt+Right

Comment: Since I have to press `AltGr`+9 to get `]`, also one should assume a four finger shortcut on my Scandinavian keyboard, but `ctrl+shift+altgr+9` gives me `9`.

Comment: @karlkoeller It's a bit annoying as commenting and uncommenting are pretty frequent.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text does that with Ctrl-/. It is not free though.