# Short way of using comment character `%` in multilines

Tags: comments

I have a long calculation in my document that starts and ends with several `\align` environments. But now, I want to make all these lines to appear as a comment since there is a possibility for them to be wrong. I know I can delete them, but I want to keep them for future reference and also I will use some parts of it in my new calculation (which I hope will be correct this time). I have tried to put `%` in front of the `\begin{align}` lines but it didn't work. I don't want to put the symbol `%` in front of all the lines one by one, so **is there a short way of making a huge part of the code to appear as a comment in LaTeX?**

Comment: We've had questions on this before (and a dupe will doubtless appear), but if you really just want to comment lots of lines then your editor should be able to help. For example, I use TeXworks and it has a shortcut for 'comment this block' and 'uncomment this block'.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17816/15925

Comment: I use TeXStudio. I have searched the site before asking the question but I somehow missed the question you mentioned @Andrew Swann, thank you.

Comment: I asked the same question to one of my friends and he just answered. I don't know whether it is only valid in TeXStudio or not but he told me to use `Ctrl + t` by selecting the whole block I want to turn into a comment and it worked for me.

Comment: For TeXstudio, commenting selected lines is done by `Ctrl+T` and uncommenting by `Ctrl+U`. These are default keyboard shortcuts and can obviously be changed.

Comment: Thank you @alesc, I may need to use the uncommenting funtion in the future as well. That was helpful.