# How can I omit everything in a certain environment?

Tags: environments

I want to create a long document that has environments for 1) problems, 2) solutions, 3) commentary.  I would like to be able to easily create the associated pdf that includes, for example, all problems and solutions, but which omits all commentary.  Is there a simple way to exclude everything that occurs within a certain environment?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Commenting out large sections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17816/5764)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily redefine an environment so that it ignores all the input.  For example, you could write

```
\newenvironment{commentary}{\iffalse}{\fi}
```

Then you can redefine `commentary` as something more useful if needed to.  If you want something easier to use, you can define a new `if` variable and use it within the definition of commentary.

Comment: should be `{\iffalse\fi}{}` instead of `{\iffalse}{\fi}`, but the edit is too short

Comment: @JoMo Why? To me it seems that with your definition commentary does nothing.

Comment: Hm, weird. And yours gave a compile error for me, if I remember correctly

Answer (score 0):

The `comment` package does just what you need.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}

\excludecomment{commentary}

\begin{document}

Problems and solutions

\begin{commentary}
This is commentary
\end{commentary}

Process commentary from now on.

\includecomment{commentary}

\begin{commentary}
This should print.
\end{commentary}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I do this with several different environments?  Sometimes I might want to include problems, but neither solutions nor commentary.  (I suppose I should look at the documentation of the comment package.)

Comment: Yes, you can do it with as many different environments as you like. If you want to put the answers at the end or in another document, see the `answers` package.