# Disable/Enable Comment Block With Macro?

Tags: macros, comments

Is there a way to make a macro within a LaTeX document, which would enable or disable a comment block?  I do this sort of thing in C and C++, but am not sure about LaTeX.

For example, near the top of the document I would like some sort of line(s) which have a 0 or a 1.  I would change between the 0 and 1 at my discretion.  If 0, then my later portion would look like:

```
\begin{comment}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{BLARG.jpg}
    \caption{\label{fig:}HONK.}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
\end{comment}
```

But if the macro number were 1, it would disable the comment function, so it would effectively leave the document with:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{BLARG.jpg}
    \caption{\label{fig:}HONK.}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE! I've taken the liberty to edit the formatting a little. In the future, you can simply highlight your code and press Ctrl+K so that the entire code appears in the grey box.

Comment: You should consider using the `comment` package.

Comment: @DavidRobie: Your original question was closed as a duplicate of [Commenting out large sections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17816/5764). Do you think your question is similar to that one and we should close your question as such? Alternatively or in addition to, do you have any feedback regarding [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353939/5764)?

Comment: @Werner: I think that the questions are essentially different.  Your answer was fantastic, and works exactly how I hoped it would.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... if you write your own `comment` environment using [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ,graphicx}

\NewEnviron{comment}{%
  \ifnum\keepcomment=1
  \else
    \BODY
  \fi
}

%\newcommand{\keepcomment}{1}% Keep comment
\newcommand{\keepcomment}{0}% Remove comment

\begin{document}

Some text before the figure.

\begin{comment}
  \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{\label{fig:example}Example image.}
  \end{figure}
\end{comment}

Some text after the figure.

\end{document}
```

---

If you're using the [`comment` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment) you can do something similar:

```
\usepackage{comment}

%\newcommand{\keepcomment}{1}% Keep comment
\newcommand{\keepcomment}{0}% Remove comment

\AtBeginDocument{\ifnum\keepcomment=1
  \excludecomment{comment}
\else
  \includecomment{comment}
\fi}
```

Comment: Please. We already have http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17816/5763 - this question is clearly a duplicate.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: I disagree. This is not about commenting out sections in general, but about providing a flag (in macro form) that can be used as a switch.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: As the person who posed the question, I would also disagree.  The one you refer to is asking for how to use \begin{comment}, but I would like to have a control sequence at the top of the document which enables/disables all instances of \begin{comment} so that I can switch all commented sections on/off, while retaining the two lines to make the comment block work, and without manually changing each one to enable/disable it.

Werner: Thanks for the answer friend!  This looks like the sort of thing I wanted!