# How to make group comment in LaTex

Tags: comments

There are lots of ways to make comment in `LaTex` such as single `percentage sign`, `\begin{comment}` and so on, but as I know none of them use for creating comment for separating lines of a doc. It's good to know there is a way  to make a group comment in `LaTex`.

ie:

```
we have text and command here and want to be comment(group1)
.
.
.
we have text and command here and want not to be comment(group2)
.
.
.
we have text and command here and want to be comment(group1)
.
.
.
we have text and command here and want not to be comment(group2)
```

and other groups, now we want to comment one group and see result and then comment other group and uncomment first group and so on.
for a bit challenging imagine that this groups of comment are  distribute
in multiple **file** (not all file but a part of it like one line in chapter 1, two lines in chapter 2, three lines in chapter 8 and ...).

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the `comment` package.

Comment: Your question is answered in [Commenting out large sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17816/5764). However, you already mention you're using `comment`. Did you know you can specify a different environment to be similar to `comment`, like `commentA`, `commentB`, ... That way you can switch them on/off as you need.

Comment: Is your aim to have a document for multiple audiences? Then you might want to add this, because this would have different approaches.

Comment: @cfr I read [comment package doc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment?lang=en) in section _special comments_ it explains how to group some commands in one comment but I'm not I can use it with same name in multiple separated files as I explained in above. if you have an Idea I would be appreciated. 
@Werner thanks dude we have general way in there so I guess I can do like this `\newif\ifstateA ,\newif\ifstateB and ... , \stateAtrue or \stateAfalse ... , \ifStateA .....  \fi`  .
@TeXnician Its be good to have a general approach for this type of comments,better calls`situational group comment`.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking. If @TeXnician is right, then we are not actually talking about comments, as far as I can tell. At least, I don't see the connection. (Unless it is just that some audiences shouldn't see some parts, while others should. Then you might say the content should be 'commented' for the first audience, but not for the second.)

Comment: You may want to have a look at the `multiaudience` package.