# Not rendering ("commenting") texts with specific colors

Tags: macros, color, comments

Suppose I have made notes, either inline or a couple of paragraphs, in different colors (e.g., `\textcolor{Aquamarine}{...}`, `\textcolor{cyan}{...}`, `\textcolor{Orange}{...}`, etc.).
Now I want to treat all texts in `Orange` and `cyan` as comments such that they are removed in the compiled PDF, without having to manually wrap them between `\begin{comment} ... \end{comment}` (of `comment` package).

Is there a nice way of doing that, like a command/macro ([using](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17818/166234) `\iffalse ... \fi`?) that takes a list of colors to be omitted and does the job?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to replace all your `\textcolor` commands with a custom macro (that either outputs colour or nothing depending on a list )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My approach would be the following: define you own macro. For example, `\myorangetext`; then use a global search and replace to change every occurrence of `textcolor{Orange}` into `myorangetext`; rinse, repeat.

Now you can do simply this thing:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\EatOneArg}[1]{}
\newcommand{\myorangetext}{\textcolor{Orange}}
\newcommand{\myaquatext}{\textcolor{Aquamarine}}
%
% comment or uncomment these
%
% \renewcommand{\myorangetext}{\EatOneArg}
\renewcommand{\myaquatext}{\EatOneArg}

\begin{document}
    And this is my code
    \myaquatext{Some text Aquamarine},
    some text without color,
    \myorangetext{some text in Orange}
\end{document}
```

Commenting or not each redefinition of your command you can change the appearance of it... and if in the future you want to change the Orange text into for example a footnote you can do it...

```
\renewcommand{\myaquatext}{\footnote}
```

The main philosophical difference here is that, defining your own macro, you do not state *how to print* some text, but *what the text IS*: this is the fundamental idea about LaTeX: describe semantically, not visually, keep content and visualization as separate as possible.

(So, really, *do not* name the macros `\myorangetext` and so on: call them `\commentforFred` or `\commentforProf` or whatever they really *mean*)

Comment: Wow, super elegant! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the `\commentColor` you set, and redefining `\textcolor`, here is a solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later
\usepackage{xstring}
\let\textcolorold\textcolor
\def\commentColor{Orange}
\RenewDocumentCommand\textcolor{mm}{\IfStrEq{#1}{\commentColor}{}{\textcolorold{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}
    And this is my code
    \textcolor{Aquamarine}{Some text}, \textcolor{cyan}{Not a comment}, \textcolor{Orange}{considered as comment}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! There is an issue, though: I cannot do that for multiple comments at the same time. Any possible fix?

Comment: It works, so +1, but it is very danger to change internal commands...

Comment: @Rmano Sure, it's an ugly fix! It would be better to define a new macro for that, but that's not what OP want (for what I understand…)

Comment: I'm a newbie in TeX, so to me command and macro were indistinguishable. @Rmano's answer is indeed a better solution.