# Uncommand a self-defined tikzbox in the final version

Tags: tikz-pgf

For a draft, I have defined a box as

```
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[linecolor=BurntOrange,backgroundcolor=BurntOrange!20, roundcorner=5pt, font=\small]{pf}
```

and in the tex, I use `\begin{pf} some texts \end{pf}`.

In the final, I don't need these `{pf}` boxes. To command it out, one way is to use `%` (the simplest I have used so far).

But, now I am wondering is there any simpler way to do so? I used `\ifdraft`, didn't work.

Comment: Can you clarify if you just want to comment the box around "some texts", or do you want to comment the box including the "some texts" inside the box?

Comment: Please also add a small test document which we can compile instead of this code fragment.

Comment: Looks like you want the functionality provided by the `comment` package
https://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Commenting out large sections](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/commenting-out-large-sections), i.e., [Daniel's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62096/277964).

Comment: Thank you. The comment package solved my problem