# How to manage bibliography files with a VCS while they're used by an external program?

Tags: bibliographies, git, organisation

I use Mendeley to organise citations. It exports a `.bib` file automatically to a folder on my Mac.

I also have another `.bib` file that I use for other citations not stored in Mendeley (websites mostly). This file is stored in a folder containing all my LaTeX projects in separate folders.

The reason that the `.bib` files are stored separate of the LaTeX project is that multiple projects use the same citations and this way I only have to maintain one `.bib` file (the other one is maintained by Mendeley).

Inspired by [the question on VCS](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1118/13134) I added my current LaTeX project to bitbucket.org using git.
It is a directory that contains my `.tex` files and images, *not* the `.bib` file.

In my `main.tex` I include the two bibliographies as follows:

```
\bibliography{~/Documents/Dropbox/Mendeley/library,../other_refs}
```

My goal now is to make the repository self-contained, so that someone can just clone it and compile the LaTeX document.

As my `.bib` files are not in the repo, how can I achieve this?
[Symlinks are not an option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1500772/1256347) as git does not follow symlinks anymore.

Comment: Sorry, but this sounds like a Git/VCS question not a (La)TeX one: looks off-topic to me.

Comment: Maybe the `bibexport` script can be what you want

Comment: @egreg thanks for the suggestion. Just tried `bibexport` and unfortunately it doesn't work well. It doesn't recognize some citation types like `electronic` or `misc`. This result in a `.bib` file that is broken and needs to be manually fixed.

Comment: You can modify `export.bst` to add fields, see the documentation; for new entries like `@electronic`, I believe it's sufficient to add a `FUNCTION` at the end, similar to the existing ones. Maybe you can look also to `bibextract.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended switching from `natbib` to `biblatex`+`biber`.
The latter supports the `\addbibresources[location=remote]` command that can use a link to a `.bib` file as an input.

```
\bibliography{~/Documents/Dropbox/Mendeley/library,../other_refs}
```

became:

```
\IfFileExists{../thesis_refs.bib}
{
    \addbibresource{~/Documents/Dropbox/Mendeley/library.bib}
    \addbibresource{../thesis_refs.bib}
}
{
    \addbibresource[location=remote,type=file]{https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/library.bib}
    \addbibresource[location=remote,type=file]{https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/thesis_refs.bib}
}
\printbibliography
```

Now a check is carried out if the local `.bib` files are present. If so, it just uses them, if not it downloads the `.bib` files from Dropbox where I've made them publicly available (the links shown here are not the actual links).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by copying the bib into the local folder using a make-file (being called by latexmk). That way you also have the right version in your repo. One of the main issues I had with Mendely was that the order of the entries changes every time the file is written. So I extended the Makefile to run it through `bibtool`. My Makefile is a bit more complex, but for you it would boil down to:

```
PROJECT.bib:~/Documents/Dropbox/Mendeley/library
        cat $< | bibtool -o $@ -r ./bib.rsc
```

And the bib.rsc looks like

```
resource {sort_fld.rsc}
sort                     = on
preserve.keys            = on
preserve.key.case        = on
```